# Want to get the result of a query into a textbox in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

my objective is to get the result of a query into a textbox.I want to be able to get the name associated with the code i written in a textbox above in another textbox.The code i have written is showing only the query in the textbox not the results of it. 
Here is the code:

```
private void btnassociar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string codigo,pesquisanome;

    codigo = txtcodigo.Text;
    pesquisanome = "select nome from produto where cod_produto like '%" + codigo + "%'";
    txtnomeassociado.Text = pesquisanome;

}
```

Comment: You need to execute the query and display the result in the textbox

Comment: I know , thats what i want to do but i dont know how

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of what you can do. You have to execute the query, and read the result.

```
string queryString = "select nome from produto where cod_produto like '%" + codigo + "%'";
public string connectionString= "Data Source=Kadfas;Initial Catalog=PowerBI;Integrated Security=True";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           // get the results here
           reader.GetString(0); // result of the first field.
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Always call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me underlining in all the sql related things, i know i am missing a 'using' but i dont know wich one.

Comment: using System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: It's also worth noting that the SqlCommand and SqlDataReader objects should also be enclosed in "using" tags, or explicitly disposed when you are done with them.

Comment: It says the name 'connection string' doesnt exist in this context , but i dont think it does what i want to , because i want to populate with those data so then i can send to a listbox and then to another part of the db so i can make a receipt printer

Comment: You need to assign your connection string to the database and store it as a string in the variable connectionstring

Comment: @RicardoPires when you get red squiggles underneath, you can right click -> resolve -> select the one you want to import, that is typically what I do.